# Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) (2016)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, mount

This in regards to the issue below

```
kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block-oo-swapper
```

I got this error after a update, I'm booting from a live cd to repair, the live cd verison is 14.4 my version is 16.04. I'm still somewhat new to repairing errors in ubuntu.

I'm using this method to repair

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/sdax /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
```

and now you can make `update-initramfs` and `update-grub` without errors

```
update-initramfs -u -k 2.6.38-8-generic (or your version)
update-grub2
```

And reboot your system

I got this error below

```
WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_5yZw8L/lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic/modules.order
```